# How to set name suffix when creating a contact via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, contacts, azure-ad-graph-api

In Outlook you can set a name suffix when creating a contact (see screenshot):
[image]

Is it possible to set this property via Microsoft Graph API? I don't find a matching property in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-beta.

The `Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.Contact` class of the C# Graph API has a dictionary `AdditionalData`. Maybe it's possible to add the suffix here? If so, I don't know the key.

Comment: Have you run a GET to see what comes back when a contact has that populated? That may help you.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. It is the property "generation". Who would think of that?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you are right. The equivalent property of **`suffix`** when
> creating a contact via Microsoft Graph API is **generation**.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **Contacts.ReadWrite** permission in it:

[image]

To create a contact with **suffix** property via Microsoft Graph API, I used below sample code:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Contact
{
    GivenName = "Sri",
    Surname = "Devi",
    Generation = "B.Tech",
    EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>
    {
        new EmailAddress
        {
            Address = "sri@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
            Name = "Sridevi",
        },
    },
    BusinessPhones = new List<string>
    {
        "+91 9xxxx84004",
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Users["userId"].Contacts.PostAsync(requestBody);

Console.WriteLine("Contact created successfully with suffix");
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in user's contacts, new contact created successfully with **suffix** like below:

[image]

To **confirm** whether it is added in **suffix** or not, you can click on **`Edit`** option and check properties:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/klF5cKm.png)]